# What is a fairly exhaustive list for how decimal numbers are written in source code?

Tags: floating-point

What is an exhaustive as possible list of examples of floating-point literals as they are written in source code?

That is, the float is not parsed from a text file with arbitrary floats.

The float literal must is written in correct syntax for a programming language such that one or both of the following:

> - the computer language is mainstream today.
> - the computer language was main-stream in the past.

double-precision is allowed, single-precision is allowed, any precision is allowed, base 16, base 8, etc...

If you understand the question, then you can stop reading the question now.

---

The string representation you provide for floating point must be used by the parser, or interpreter, or compiler for source code in one or more language which is well-used in the present or was well-used used in the past such as [java-script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), [Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran), [Intel x86 assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language), [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java), etc...

If the terms "mainstream" and "well-used" are too subjective for your taste, then the following list might help:

> [**Intel x86 Assembly language**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language)
> [**Fortran**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran)
> [**C**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language))
> [**Java**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))
> ABAP
> ABL
> Ada
> Assembly
> Awk
> Bash (Bourne Again Shell) script
> C
> C#
> C++
> CFML
> COBOL
> D
> Dart
> Delphi/Object
> F#
> Fortran
> FoxPro
> Go
> Groovy
> Haskell
> Java
> JavaScript
> Julia
> Kotlin
> Lisp
> Logo
> Lua
> MATLAB
> Objective-C
> OpenEdge
> Perl
> PHP
> PL/SQL
> PowerShell
> Prolog
> Python
> R
> Ruby
> Rust
> SAS
> Scala
> Scheme
> Scratch
> SQL
> Swift
> Transact-SQL
> TypeScript
> Visual
> Visual Basic
> Zig

This is a publicly editable wiki, so feel free to add more to it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the purpose of this question. Why make such a list? Can you edit it to add context as to why it is a question about teaching?

Answer (score 1):

3.14e2
3.14e-67f
.14E4f
0x10.1p0
0x1p5
0x1e5
3.14'15'92
3.14e-4932l
3.14e38f
3.14e38
3.14e38l
3.14_15F
10_000_000.0
+1.23E+1
3.1415926D0
5.d0
1.
0xfadebeep-8

Comment: `0xfadebeep-8` is not a decimal.